# Submitting Sitemap.xml to Google

Tags: magento, xml-sitemap

How frequently it is recommended to generate and upload Sitemap.xml to Google for an e-commerce site where products are added and removed on daily basis?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can set cron job to run daily. The instruction to set up cron job can be found here

[Magento and Google Sitemap - Cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10654875/magento-and-google-sitemap-cron)